# MVC, C# WebGrid in PartialView, delete rows with Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a `WebGrid` and a link used for row deletion inside a `PartialView` defined like this -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteThis", "MyController", new { id = SelectedId }, null)
<div id="MyGrid">
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.ListOfStuff, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "MyGrid");   


    @grid.GetHtml()
}
</div>
```

After as item on the grid is selected, the user can click the "Delete" link to delete the row from the database.

My problem is, I want to make that call an **Ajax** call *and* update the grid after the deletion. My sorts are working in an Ajax manner, but I can't figure out how to get the "Delete" to work with Ajax. My Controller code looks like this -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //CODE TO RETRIEVE THE MODEL

        return PartialView("Index", model);
    }

    public ActionResult DeleteThis(string id)
    {
        ////CODE TO DELETE RECORD

        return RedirectToAction("Index");  // I ALSO TRIED return PartialView("Index", model)         }
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for the click event of the link and make an ajax call to the action method which does the delete functionality.

Make sure that your `DeleteThis` method is decorated with `HttpPost` attribute. Delete should be always a **HttpPost** action. Not a GET action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteThis(string id)
{
  try
  {
  // to do : delete
   return Json(new { Status="Deleted"});
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //log the error
   return Json(new { Status="Error"});
  } 
}
```

From your Action method you are returning a JSON. In your post method's callback, check the Status property value to see whether the delete operation was successful or not.

```
$(function(){

  $("#SelectedId").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedItemId=34; // you need to get this from the grid;

    $.post("@Url.Action("DeleteThis","Home")/"+selectedItemId,function(data){
         if(data.Status="Deleted")
         {
          //reload the page or just reload the partial view as needed
          window.location.href=window.location.href;
          // $("#GridContainer").load(@Url.Action("List","Users")");
         }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju! This doesn't seem like it will refresh the grid though. Is that correct?

Comment: @ABogus you can refresh either the whole page or just reload the grid only using another ajax call(see the commented line which uses `load` method to reload the part of the page)